# I need to ask for a 'Case in-sensitive' code for scanner input. any advice accepted

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, uppercase, lowercase

I wondered: is there a way to make the reading of scanner input
 'case in-sensitive' whitout lower or upper case? 
I have to make lots of 'Y' or 'N' answers and I have to convert each scanner input to String, and then using '.toUpperCase'  '.toLowerCase'.
 I feel like I'm missing something more practical...

My other idea was to create a scanner class that converts every input to string and then to Upper/LowerCase, but my question is basically if there is any way to set that from start that I might be missing...

```
public void acariciar(ArrayList<Animal> animales) {
    System.out.println("Quiere acariciar a estos animales?? Y ó N");

    String inputDeUsuario = escaner.nextLine();
    if (inputDeUsuario.toUpperCase().equals("Y")) {
        for (Animal animal : animales) {
            animal.acariciado();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try equalsIgnoreCase instead of equals. This has nothing to do with scanner, it's provided by the String classµ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "case insensitive input" - a Latin letter is inherently either uppercase or lowercase. But you can ask for the *comparison* to ignore the case differences between each character pair of the strings being compared, with [`String.equalsIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-):

```
inputDeUsuario.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")
```

(If you are in a situation where you don't control the equality comparison, e.g. if you're adding strings to a `HashSet`, you're doing it the right way: pick either lowercase or uppercase, and convert everything to that case.)